# visualize microphone audio in Java

Tags: java, visualization, microphone

Is there a way to visualize audio in Java in a kind of wave?

How should I start, I already set up a microphone selection an a Thread to read the bytes from the TargetDataLine into a buffer.
But what should I do now?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ahh Greetz ... reminds me of the Warez days.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Java Sound API, the data that you have read is 8 or 16 bits PCM. If it is 8-bit then it is fine, otherwise you may need to adjust the [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

If you are reading 8-bit PCM, each byte is a sample, then the value of that byte is the sound sample. If you are reading 16-bit PCM, then the samples are packed either as `hi,lo,hi,lo` or `lo,hi,lo,hi` (where hi and lo are high and low order bytes) depending on endianness. In that case you should convert that to a short value.

For plotting you will need a 3rd party library, such as [freechart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/) or [jahuwaldt.plot](http://thehuwaldtfamily.org/java/Packages/Plot/PlotPackage.html). (I used the latter on a real time wave visualization program).

Comment: Ok, I found this to PCM:
http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=PCM
How do I adjust endianess and how can I calculate my plots?

Comment: Yes but I mean how do I convert the PCM bytes from the TargetDataLine to data which I can plot?

Comment: So, i got it up to the shorts! :)
How could i make a simple bar indicating the current loudness?
Like in skype when you test you microphone or something like that...
Just a bar that is bigger when there's a louder noise?